# Specialize a function template in c++?

Tags: c++, function, sorting, templates, predicate

I have to create a generic function to sort strings in C++, and I have to test it with my own string class (which I have implemented as `SuchString`).

I have a template like this:

```
template<typename T, class Sel>
void stringSort(T& lel);
```

the `Sel` class contains a predicate function to determine what to sort by.

I want to specialize the sorting function, so it can work properly with my own `SuchString` class:

```
template<>
void stringSort<SuchString&>(SuchString& string);
```

When I do that, I get the error:

> No function template matches function template specialization '`stringSort`'

What is the proper way to specialize a function like this? I can't simply overload the function because I need the `Sel` class containing the predicate function. I can't pass this function as a simple pointer parameter
to the function because the task is to use templates.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Dont use function specialization. Use class specialization for this. And dispatch the call to the static member function of the class (template and specialization).

Comment: I don't understand your last paragraph - why can't you pass the function as a function pointer? You can just take it as a template argument - that's how `std::sort` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original template function contains *two* types:

```
template<typename T, class Sel>
void stringSort(T& lel);
```

You're trying to specialize it with only *one* type. Hence the error. I don't exactly understand how you're using `Sel` here. I'm assuming you really meant to pass that in as an argument:

```
template<typename T, typename Sel>
void stringSort(T& lel, Sel predicate);
```

In which case, the simpler thing to do is to just provide an overload for `SuchString`:

```
template <typename Sel>
void stringSort(SuchString&, Sel );
```

The overload will be preferred to the template.

If what you need is really a static method on `Sel`, then you'll need to simply switch the ordering of the template types:

```
template <typename Sel, typename T>
void stringSort(T& );

template <typename Sel>
void stringSort(SuchString& );
```

That way, `stringSort<SomeSel>(foo)` will call the `SuchString&` overload if `foo` is an lvalue of type `SuchString`, and the `T&` version otherwise.